# Fundamental group of covering space of a figure eight

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

[image]

I had a question about computing fundamental groups of certain covering spaces. In Hatcher's book, he claims that all of these groups can be computed from Van Kampen. I could figure them out for a few, but am not sure how to show this for covering space 11. I am not sure how to pick the open sets $A_{\alpha}$ for Van Kampen. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Van Kampen to the intersection of the graph with a blob around each $a$ loop which covers slightly more than half of the neighbouring $b$ intervals, I call these subsets "pieces".

Each piece has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and the intersections of neighbouring pieces are $1$-connected.

So starting with one piece we have $\pi_{1} = \mathbb{Z}$, and every we time we add a neighbouring piece we make a free product with $\mathbb{Z}$ (since the intersection is $1$-connected) giving after $k$ steps the free group of $k$ generators; $F_k$.

In the end we get a free group on a countably infinite generating set. It is a nice geometric  was to see that $F_2$ has a non finitely generated subgroup (generated by elements of the form $b^n a b^{-n}$)

Comment: Oh, I get it now.! Thanks for clarifying. I had made a mistake in assuming the intersection was of all the pieces, but its only pairwise intersections. That makes sense.